# Short story first contact - Earth can ask anyone a question and nobody can answer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, first-contact

It's a short story about making first contact.
I can remember than the Earth is able to ask a question, but nobody can answer it.

In the end some army attacks the place they are going to send the question from, forcing the guy who first heard it, to ask the question.
I also think there was a side plot about his son being there too.

Comment: @user14111 I edited the way I understood the question. As I have not enough reputation, my edits need to be reviewed. So, I made it with my way of thinking, counting on the more skilled reviewer to accept or not.
As you said, the original question was some kind of a mess :/

Comment: @Saphirel OK. It would be nice if we could get some clarifications from the OP

Comment: How long ago did you read the story? Please tell us everything you can remember about it. Don't worry about spoiling it. Who is earth asking, the aliens? What was the question? Did we get an answer? What are the aliens like—humanoids, insectoids, blobs, robots? Are they friendly, neutral, or hostile?